Existence of sequence converging point-wise to sup in chain of uniformly bounded functions
I am quite new to posets, and I am trying to understand what I believe is a well known property (or a claim that is well known to be false in general).
Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal F_X$ denote the class of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. We can define a partial ordering on $\mathcal F_X$, saying that $f\geq g$ if $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. A subset $C\subseteq\mathcal F_X$ is a chain if it is fully ordered (namely, for any pair of elements $f$ and $g$ it is true that either $f\geq g$ or $g\geq f$). Consider a chain $C$ that is uniformly bounded, namely there is $h\in\mathcal F_ X$ such that for any $f\in C$ we have $f\leq h$.
Now, for each $x\in X$, we have that $\sup_{f\in C}f(x)$ is well defined, since $\{f(x):f\in C\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ bounded from above by $h(x)<\infty$. So, I can define $g\in\mathcal F_X$ as $g(x) = \sup_{f\in C}f(x)$. I believe $g$ is what is called the supremum of $C$, since it is the least majoriser in $\mathcal F_X$.
Is it always true that there exists a sequence $(f_n)\subseteq C$ that converges point-wise to $g$?
I am probably making things over complicated, but although it seems obvious to me that it should be true, I cannot think of a simple way to show it. For each $x$, I know that there is an increasing sequence of functions in $C$ whose values on $x$ converge to $g(x)$. But of course, this same sequence might be not converging for some other value $x'\in X$. For instance, assume that $g(x) = g(x')=1$. I might have a sequence $f_n$ such that $f_n(x) = 1-1/n$ and $f_n(x')=0$. Then clearly the sequence is converging to $g(x)$ on $x$ but it is not converging to $g(x')$ on $x'$.
If I have finitely many points things can work. For instance let's say that I have $N$ points $X=\{x_1\dots x_N\}$. For each $i=1\dots n$ I consider an increasing sequence $f^i_n$ such that $f^i_n(x_i)\to g(x_i)$. Then I can define $f_n = \max_{i=1\dots N}f_n^i$ (which is well defined since all the $f_n^i$ are in $C$ and so are mutually comparable). Then, clearly $f_n(x)\to g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.
I think I can extend this approach to the case where $X$ is countable. Then we have $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$. Again, for any $i$ construct an increasing sequence $f_n^i$ such that $f_n^i(x_i)\to g(x_i)$. Now, the sequence $f_n = \max_{i=1\dots n}f_n^i$ is well defined for any $n$ and converges point-wise to $g$.
However, I don't see how to extend this to the case when $X$ is uncountable, for instance the interval $[0,1]$. Is it always possible to define the point-wise limit? Otherwise is there an explicit counterexample?

I assume that your main (or only) question in the one typesetter in bold. That said, I find it very unclear what you're asking. The hypothesis seems to be that $C$ is a chain with a top element. But then, what are the elements that make a sequence converging to $g$? Then in the following paragraph you seem to turn the reasoning backwards and present a candidate $g$ for a given subset of elements. Could you clarify?

@amrsa I've tried to reformulate the question a bit (yes the bold question is the question, what appears later are attempts to answer it). Let me know if it is still unclear though.

The property is false.
Let $X = |\mathbb{R}|$ (the cardinal number of $\mathbb{R}$). Consider $C = \{ f_{\alpha} : \alpha \in X \}$ with $f_{\alpha} : X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f_{\alpha}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \leqslant \alpha, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
So essentially $f_{\alpha} = \chi_{(\leftarrow, \alpha]}$, where $(\leftarrow, \alpha]$ is the initial segment of $X$ consisting of elements up to $\alpha$.
Clearly $C$ is a chain because $f_{\alpha} \leqslant f_{\beta}$ if $\alpha \leqslant \beta$. Also $C$ is bounded from above by the constant function $1$. We will show there is no sequence in $C$ that converges pointwise to an upper bound of $C$.
Assume for contradiction that $(g_n) \subseteq C$ is such a sequence. Then each $g_n$ equals $f_{\alpha_n}$ for some $\alpha_n \in X$. Since $X$ has uncountable cofinality, there is an upper bound $\alpha \in X$ of $\{ \alpha_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. But then $g_n \leqslant f_{\alpha}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and so $g_n$ converges to $0$ for all inputs $x > \alpha$, which is a contradiction.

A deeper analysis
We need to introduce some notions first.

Assume $T$ is a linear order.

A cut of $T$ is a pair of its subsets $(A, B)$ such that $A \cup B = T$ and $a < b$ for each $a \in A$, $b \in B$. For the purposes of this post we call the cut proper if $(A, B) \neq (T, \varnothing)$.
The family $\hat{T}$ of all cuts of $T$ equipped with the relation
$$(A_1, B_1) \preccurlyeq (A_2, B_2) \qquad \text{when} \qquad A_1 \subseteq A_2$$
is a complete linear order into which $T$ embeds via $i(t) = \big( (\leftarrow, t), [t, \rightarrow) \big)$. We will identify $T$ with $i[T] \subseteq \hat{T}$.
A subset $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \hat{T}$ dominates $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \hat{T}$ if for every $c \in \mathcal{C}$ there is $d \in \mathcal{D}$ with $c \preccurlyeq d$.
A subset $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \hat{T}$ is cofinal if it dominates $T$.


Consider an arbitrary set $X$ and a chain $C \subseteq \mathcal{F}_X$. As you noticed, there exists $s = \sup C$ given by the formula $s(x) = \sup_{f \in C} f(x)$. If $s \in C$, the problem is trivial, so let us focus on the case $s \notin C$.
Given any $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, we have that the pair
$$\begin{align*}
A_{x, \varepsilon} & = \{ f \in C : f(x) < s(x) - \varepsilon \} \\
B_{x, \varepsilon} & = \{ f \in C : f(x) \geqslant s(x) - \varepsilon \}
\end{align*}$$
forms a proper cut of $C$. Note that a sequence $(f_n) \subseteq C$ converges pointwise to $g$ if and only if for every $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ we have that $f_n \in B_{x, \varepsilon}$ for sufficiently large $n$.
Claim 1. Such a sequence exists if and only if there exists a countable subset of $C$ that dominates the set of cuts $\mathcal{C} = \{ (A_{x, \varepsilon}, B_{x, \varepsilon}) : x \in X, \varepsilon > 0 \}$.
Proof. If the sequence exists, then clearly $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ dominates $\mathcal{C}$. For the converse, assume a countable subset $D = \{ g_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq C$ dominates $\mathcal{C}$ and let $f_n = \max_{i \leqslant n} g_i$. Then $(f_n)$ is the required sequence. $\square$
We now see that the question is really about being able to dominate a particular set of cuts ($\mathcal{C}$) with a countable subset of $C$.
Remark. The set $\mathcal{C}$ is dominated by its subset where epsilons are taken from a fixed sequence converging to $0$, e.g. $\frac{1}{m}$. In other words, the set
$$\mathcal{C}' = \{ (A_{x, \frac{1}{m}}, B_{x, \frac{1}{m}}) : x \in X, m \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
dominates $\mathcal{C}$. This immediately implies a positive answer to the question when $X$ is countable, because a countable set of proper cuts can always be dominated with a countable subset of the order. $\square$
Claim 2. The set $\mathcal{C}$ is cofinal.
Proof. Take any $f \in C$. Since $f < s$, we have $f(x) < s(x)$ for some $x \in X$. For a sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$ we then have $f(x) < s(x) - \varepsilon$. It follows that $f \preccurlyeq (A_{x, \varepsilon}, B_{x, \varepsilon})$, as required. $\square$
Therefore dominating $\mathcal{C}$ is the same as dominating the whole chain $C$. The question thus becomes equivalent to deciding if $C$ always admits a countable cofinal subset. In other words, we ask whether $C$ must have countable cofinality.
The classical example of a linear order with uncountable cofinality is the least uncountable cardinal, $\omega_1$. If we could arrange for the chain $C$ to be isomorphic to $\omega_1$, this would give a natural negative answer to the main question. This is indeed possible: if $X = \omega_1$ and $C = \{ \chi_{(\leftarrow, \alpha]} : \alpha \in \omega_1 \}$, the mapping $\alpha \mapsto \chi_{(\leftarrow, \alpha]}$ is an isomorphism between $\omega_1$ and $C$. My initial example with $X = |\mathbb{R}|$ is simply a variation of this construction - $|\mathbb{R}|$ is just another known example of a linear order with uncountable cofinality.

Thanks! Nice counter example. But is uncountable cofinality of X necessary? For instance for $X=\mathbb R$ would a counter example still exist? (Maybe it is possible to put an order on $\mathbb R$ so that it is uncountable cofinite, but I am really unfamiliar with this stuff, so apologies for the perhaps trivial question).

@ECL The counterexample for $X_1 = |\mathbb{R}|$ automatically gives a counterexample for each $X_2$ with $|X_2| = |X_1|$: just fix a bijection $\varphi : X_1 \to X_2$ and "push/pull" everything through it. In particular $X = \mathbb{R}$ admits a counterexample of the very same nature. Going a bit deeper, I think the notion of cardinality is necessary to completely understand the problem. I will try to include in the answer why I think this is the case.

I meant "cofinality", not "cardinality".

@ECL I've added a comprehensive analysis of the problem that hopefully clarifies why the notion of cofinality, particularly that which is uncountable, plays a central role in the solution.

Thanks for the edited answer! I was wondering if such construction would be possible if one adds measurability assumptions. Like if $X=[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-field, and all the element of the chain have to be measurable. In such a case I guess when giving $[0,1]$ an order that gives it uncountable cofinality, I guess the initial segment would be non-measurable. So would a counter-example still be possible? In case you find the question interesting, I've just posted a new related question... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4994398
