(non-)measurability of sup of chain of functions
Consider the interval $I=[0,1]$, endowed with the Borel sigma-field. Let $\mathcal F$ denote the space of all measurable functions. We can endow this space with a partial ordering by saying that $f\succeq g$ iff $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Now, let $C$ denote a chain in this space, namely a totally ordered subset of $\mathcal F$. Assume that the chain is uniformly bounded by the constant $1$. Then there exists a supremum (namely least majoriser) of the chain (which is the point-wise sup $x\mapsto\sup_{f\in C}f(x)$). In general, the supremum of a family of measurable function does not have to be measurable. So, I believe the sup of the chain can be non-measurable. Clearly the sup is measurable if there is a sequence of functions in $C$ that converges point-wise to the sup, but this might be not always the case (see Existence of sequence converging point-wise to sup in chain of uniformly bounded functions, although no measurability was discussed there and I think, although I am not entirely sure, that trying to replicate the construction therein via initial segments would require  non-measurable functions in the chain).
I would like to see an explicit counter-example of a chain whose sup is non-measurable. The standard example of non-measurable sup is built with the Vitali set $\Gamma$ on $[0,1]$ (or any other non-measurable set), by defining the family $\{\mathbf{1}_{\gamma}\}_{\gamma\in\Gamma}$. However this is clearly not a chain. One could try to make it a chain by defining $f_\gamma = \sum_{\gamma'\leq\gamma}1_{\gamma'} = \mathbf{1}_{[0,\gamma]\cap\Gamma}$, but clearly these functions aren't measurable. So I am wondering if such a counterexample actually exists, or if a chain must have a measurable supremum.
Edit. I thought that one could perhaps use the lattice supremum to show that the limit must be measurable, but I now doubt that it would work. I know that the chain must have a lattice supremum, namely a function $\bar f$ that is measurable, such that for each $f\in C$ we have $f\leq\bar f$ a.e., and such that for any measurable $g$ that dominates almost anywhere any $f\in C$ we have $\bar f\leq g$ a.e. I can show that there is a sequence in $C$ that converges a.e. to $\bar f$, and in particular that $\bar f$ must be a.e. upper bounded by the point-wise supremum. If it is true that the point-wise supremum has to be almost everywhere a majoriser of the lattice supremum then we have that $\bar f$ is almost everywhere equal to the point-wise supremum, which hence would be measurable (I guess). However in general this is not true (at least for generic families that are not chains). For instance, the family $\{\mathbf{1}_x\,:\,x\in[0,1]\}$ has lattice supremum $0$ and point-wise supremum $1$. So, again one would need to exploit the fact that the family considered is a chain to make things work...

If somehow you know a nonmeasurable subset $\Gamma$ of $[0,1]$ with cardinality $\aleph_1$, you can endow $\Gamma$ with a well-order of type $\omega_1$ and then introduce $f_\gamma=\sum_{\gamma'\leq\gamma}\mathbf 1_{\gamma'}$ for every $\gamma\in\Gamma$ like you wanted to, except the order used to index the sum is the well-order on $\Gamma$.

@P.P.Tuong I see... So to clarify (I am not super familiar with cardinalities), the set $\gamma'\leq\gamma$ is countable, so measurable (so the function $f_\gamma$ is measurable), right? Is the existence of a non-measurable set with cardinality $\aleph_1$ granted (assuming AC)?

Yes, each set ${\gamma'\in\Gamma~|~\gamma'\leq\gamma}$ is countable so each $f_\gamma$ is the indicator function of a countable set. As for the existence of such a $\Gamma$ under ZFC, I have no idea. But if you addtionally assume the continuum hypothesis, any nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$. The goal of my first comment wasn't to provide a positive answer, but to say that there cannot be a negative answer, which is something like a tiny step toward an answer.

@P.P.Tuong You don't need a subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$ for the argument to work - you can just keep adding one point at a time until you get a non-measurable subset of $[0, 1]$. I have included the details in an answer.

Take a Vitali set $V \subseteq [0, 1]$ and enumerate its elements as
$$V = \{ a_{\alpha} : \alpha < \kappa \}$$
for a cardinal $\kappa$. For $\beta \leqslant \kappa$ let $V_{\beta} = \{ a_{\alpha} : \alpha < \beta \}$ and $f_{\beta} = \chi_{V_{\beta}}$.
Clearly $\{ f_{\beta} : \beta < \kappa \}$ would be a chain if it consisted of measurable functions. But if not, we can take the least $\lambda < \kappa$ such that $f_{\lambda}$ is non-measurable. Such a $\lambda$ can not be a successor ordinal, so $\{ f_{\beta} : \beta < \lambda \}$ is a chain in $\mathcal{F}$ with a non-measurable supremum $f_{\lambda}$.

Ah yes, that's pretty nice.

Thanks for the answer. I am a bit confused (actually I am not familiar at all with "successor ordinals" so maybe the answer lies simply there). I guess we cannot just take as order the one induced by the ordering on $\mathbb R$, as otherwise $\lambda=0$. So, how can I be sure that there is an ordering on $V$ so that $\lambda$ is not simply the inf of the indexing set? (I guess there will need to be infinitely many indexes smaller than $\lambda$ for the construction to work).

@ECL Ordinals come with their own order, which is a well-order - there is no need to induce the order from $\mathbb{R}$ or $V$. For each countable $\lambda < \kappa$ the set $V_{\lambda}$ is countable, hence measurable. In particular, $\lambda$ can not be $0$ (the least ordinal number) because $f_0 = \chi_{ \varnothing } \equiv 0$ is measurable.

A successor ordinal is an ordinal of the form $\alpha + 1$ for some other ordinal $\alpha$. The remaining ordinals (excluding $0$) are called limit ordinals, e.g. $\omega$. Clearly $f_{\alpha}$ is measurable if and only if $V_{\alpha}$ is measurable. Now the number $\lambda$ can not be a successor, since if $\lambda = \alpha+1$ for some $\alpha$, then $V_{\lambda} = V_{\alpha+1} = V_{\alpha} \cup { a_{\alpha} }$ and since $V_{\alpha}$ is measurable (because $\alpha < \lambda$), $V_{\lambda}$ is as well (they differ by just one element).
